# Get the address in ARM Inline assembly

Tags: inline-assembly, iar

The IAR compiler for ARM Cortex-M3 provides inline assembly. How can one store the address of a specific function to a location on the stack?

The C code would like this

```
void tick();

void bar()
{
    int x;
    // modify a value on stack
    (&x)[4] = &tick;
}
```

While this works in general it is optimized away by the compiler in release build. I have tried to code it with inline assembly

```
void bar()
{
    int x;
    asm("ldr r0,%0" : : "i" (&tick));
    asm("str r0,[sp+#0x10];
}
```

The `ldr` instruction is not accepted by the IAR compiler. The problem is that this instruction requires an addressing mode with a register and offset. The actual address of the function `tick` is store behind the function and the `ldr` instruction holds only the offset to the memory location the holds the actual address. The disassembly is similar like this:

```
    ldr r0,??tick_address
    str r0,[sp+#0x10]
    bx lr ; return
??tick_address dd tick
```

How do I get the address of `tick` immediately to a register to use it for the stack manipulation?

Comment: Is that GCC inline assembly syntax? I believe IAR allows symbols to be referenced directly in inline assembly without any extra red tape. I.e. something like `asm("ldr,=tick");`

Comment: It looks as similar to GCC syntax. But as my edit shows that LDR requires a non-immediate argument.

Comment: The IAR assembler manual lists `LDR Rd,=immed32` as a supported pseudo-instruction. It seems odd that they then wouldn't support it for inline assembly.

Comment: @Michael Yes it seems. The "i" causes the immediate-# to be prepended to the symbol. But this requires the placement of the actual value in code at the end of the function to access it at [PC+offset]. This might be a bit complicated in inline assembly.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here - the task of assigning a function pointer can be done in plain C, no assembly required at all. If anything, `asm("" : "=r"(foo) : "0"(tick))` will "assign" it. Can you provide a little more context, please ?

Comment: @FrankH. While this asm works it is not obvious why an empty asm statement emits assembly code. Can you provide a resource where this is documented? Further you could add the solution as an answer.

Comment: The `asm()` statement isn't _empty_ - it has an _input_ and an _output_. The output, `"=r"(foo)` says the variable `foo` will be returned in a register, while the input, `"0"(tick)` says the variable `tick` is to passed in via _alias_ - that is, using the same register as argument 0 (that's the `"=r"(foo)`). So the statement says, in short, pass `tick` in the same register that you afterwards take `foo` from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU GCC inline assembly can do mere *assignments* via pseudo-empty `asm()` statements, like:

```
asm("" : "=r"(foo) : "0"(tick));
```

This tells the compiler:

1. The variable `foo` is to be taken from a register after the inline assembly block
2. The variable `tick` is to be passed in - in the *same* register (argument zero)

The actual choice of which register is to be used is completely left to the compiler.

The trick here are the *output* and *input* constraints - we just *alias* the (one and only) input to the output, and the compiler will, on its own, choose a suitable register, and generate the instructions necessary to load / store the respective variables before / after the "actual" inline assembly code. You could even do:

```
asm("" : "=r"(foo1), "=r"(foo2) : "0"(tick1) , "1"(tick2));
```

to do two "assignments" in a single inline assembly statement.

This compiler-generated "set the inputs, retrieve the outputs" code generation happens even if the actual inline assembly is empty (as here).

Another example: Say you want to read the current program counter - the `PC` register. You can do that on ARM via two different inline assembly statements:

```
asm("" : "=pc"(foo));
asm("mov %0, PC" : "=r"(foo));
```

This is not 100% identical; in the second case, the compiler knows that whatever register it wants to see `foo` in *after* the `asm`, it'll find it there. In the former, the compiler knows that were it to use `foo` *after* the statement, it needs to retrieve it from `PC`. The difference between the two would be if you did:

```
uintptr_t *val;
uintptr_t foo;

asm("" : "=pc"(foo));
*val = foo;
```

In this case, the compiler can possibly identify that this can be turned into a single `str [R...], PC` because it knows `foo` is in `pc` after the asm. Were you to write this via

```
asm("mov %0, PC" : "=r"(foo));
*val = foo;
```

the compiler would be forced to create (assuming it chooses `R0` / `R1` for `foo`/`val`):

```
MOV R0, PC
STR [R1], R0
```

The documentation for this behaviour is largely [in the "Extended ASM" section of the GCC manuals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html), see the example for the contrived `combine` instruction.

Comment: Confirmed that this works in IAR.
I must also note that the input argument cannot be used as an immediate, so while 
`asm("mov r0, %0" : "=r"(foo) : "0"(tick));` works, `asm("bkpt %0" : "=r"(foo) : "0"(tick));` doesn't. But maybe somebody can point out a clever hack to circumvent this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no assignment the variable `x` in your code, therefore it's value is undefined and setting `foo` to an undefined value isn't required to change `foo`.

You need to assign the value to the variable, not to some memory location you assume the compiler use to implement it.

Comment: `x` is assigned by inline assembly.